# How to enable 7-zip right click option in the version of 7-zip 18.5 using ThinApp

Tags: windows-7

I have captured 7-zip 18.5 application using ThinApp 5.2.3 version. After registering ThinApp It doesn't appear 7-zip option on right click of folder.

I have tried below methods

1. I checked before post scan "The integrate 7-Zip and cascaded context menu" options are ticked. But still no 7-Zip options appear.

Could you please suggest how to resolve this issue in Thinapp.

Comment: This is by design. You cannot deploy shell extensions with ThinApp.

Answer (score 6):

This situations may mentions that the right click option of 7-zip can not be virtualized by thinapp.

If you just want to add right click options of 7-zip. You can try the following steps.
Method 1
Step 1: Open 7-Zip File Manager by typing 7-Zip in Start menu or Start screen and then pressing Enter key.
Step 2: Next, navigate to Tools menu and then click Options to open Options dialog.

[image]

Step 3: Here, under 7-Zip tab, make sure that Integrate 7-Zip to shell context menu option is selected. If not, please select the option and then click Apply button. You might need to reboot your PC or restart Windows Explorer to see 7-Zip in the context menu.

[image]

Method 2
Step 1: Uninstall the currently installed version of 7-Zip by navigating to Programs and Features.
[image]
Step 2: Download a fresh copy of 7-Zip from the official page and install the same but don’t launch it after the installation.
Step 3: Once 7-Zip is installed, type 7-Zip in the Start menu or Start screen and then right-click on the 7-Zip entry again and run the program with admin rights. This should fix the problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

On page 10 of the [user manual](https://www.vmware.com/pdf/thinapp50_manual.pdf), it mentions things that ThinApp cannot virtualize:

> **Shell Integration**
>
> Some applications that provide shell integration have reduced functions when they exist in a ThinApp package. For example, a virtual application that integrates with Windows Explorer cannot add specific entries to the Windows Explorer context menus.